# php.ini reload in php-cli

Tags: php, php-ini

I have php script that must be runned from console (php-cli). But configuration of php.ini for php-cli was incorrect. I fix it, but when I run script a had error with php config, because php.ini uses an old.

How I can reload php.ini for console without restart server?

Comment: add some more details, OS? which php.ini file is used in cli mode? do you force an ini file in you command line? how do you know an old version is used?

Answer (score 147, accepted):

The configuration is loaded fresh each time you invoke PHP from the CLI.