# Change of 'html_errors' in php.ini for CLI not taking effect

Tags: php

I'm trying to turn on `html_errors` in PHP CLI. I've already found the proper config via `php -i` and uncommented the line `html_errors = On` there.

This is how I find the config file:

```bash
$ php -i | grep 'Loaded Configuration File'
Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php/8.1/cli/php.ini
```

This is how I check the (now uncommented) directive:

```bash
$ grep 'html_errors' /etc/php/8.1/cli/php.ini
html_errors = On
```

But I still see it turned off:

```bash
$ php -i | grep 'html_errors'
html_errors => Off => Off
```

What am I missing? According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5816965/7988312), the configuration is loaded fresh each time you invoke PHP from the CLI. I also restarted my php-fpm service, but that didn't help and it shouldn't be at all related to CLI configuration.

Comment: are you using php-fpm with nginx or you have installed apache with default php events.... either way for settings to take effect properly you should restart php process...

Comment: @AnantV I'm using php-fpm with nginx. I restarted the fpm service to be sure but that shouldn't matter in CLI. It didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [the docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.differences.php) about "Remarkable differences of the CLI SAPI compared to other SAPIs", `html_errors` is set to `false` when using the CLI, and the documentation continues to say:

> These directives cannot be initialized with another value from the configuration file php.ini or a custom one (if specified). This limitation is because the values are applied after all configuration files have been parsed. However, their values can be changed during runtime...